# SSH X Tunnel via non-X server

Tags: linux, unix, ssh, tunnel, x11-forwarding

strange variation on the standard 'multi-hop tunnel' question.

I'm working remotely at the minute, but have several 'incoming' automatic reverse shells connecting to a dedicated server. This dedicated server **does not** have X, but several of the 'incoming' shell servers do.

Basically, take three machines, laptop, server, client. Laptop and client have X, server does not. All three machines have password-less logins to each other (laptop > server, server > client) and can password-lessly establish a shell.

I've tried `ssh -X user@server "ssh -X user@client gui-application"` and, no suprise, I'm getting 'Cannot open Display" messages.

Does anyone know I nice one-liner for this kind of tunnelling?

Comment: This shouldn't depend on the remote site running X or not -- all you should need is a local X server. So could you explain your setup more clearly? What server do you connect to what (what is "automatic")? Is your local X server running when you open the tunnels? And how do you use your tunnels?

Comment: the automatic is just that the servers are set up to re-establish the reverse shells if the connection drops/times out. Setup more clearly explained in update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your command actually works for me, so I don't think you need to do anything very different. However, I did find that it worked a lot more snappily if I used a `-t` option on the first ssh:

```
ssh -tX user@server "ssh -X user@client gui-application"
```

This seems to be something to do with `ssh-agent` and asking for a passphrase in my case, since my ssh keys are protected with passphrases. However, maybe it will help in your case too.

I also tried adding `-A` (agent forwarding) on both ssh commands, and this worked too, although with a delay of several seconds (not sure why). It came up with a GUI password dialog for the key for the hop from "server" to "client".

Remember that ssh with a command doesn't use `.profile` on the remote machine, so if you're relying on settings from there, that won't work, although you could probably run it explicitly with:

```
ssh -tX user@server ". .profile; ssh -X user@client gui-application"
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your hop server doesn't allow X
Set 'X11Forwarding yes' in the /etc/ssh/sshd_config of your hop server (also don't forget to restart sshd after changing the settings.

Answer (score 0):

Try punching straight through the first hop:

```
ssh -N -L 9999:client:22 user@server
ssh -p 9999 -X user@localhost gui-application
```

The first command will forward local port 9999 to the client's SSH port.  Leave this command running - it won't produce output after you log in.
The second command will SSH to your local port 9999, which is actually the "client" SSH port, and launch the GUI.

Take that for a spin.